# finding RAILS_ENV when using backup_gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, backup

I am using the piece of code provided on this [link](http://erik.debill.org/2011/03/26/csing-backup-with-rails).
For some reason I am not able to get the correct

```
RAILS_ENV    = ENV['RAILS_ENV'] || 'development'
```

no matter what I do.

What may be the reason? What is the better to get the rails env in this case?

Comment: What is the output of 'Rails.env'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For someone else looking to find a solution for the same problem. I could not find a way to pass the rails_env to the gem so the workaround was to have a static file deployed for each of the dev environments hard code the environment as development and or rails in that file and then link to that file using capistrano.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Rails 3 (or 4) then RAILS_ENV is deprecated, it's not setting the environment that way anymore so it can't retrieve that info.

Just change

```
RAILS_ENV    = ENV['RAILS_ENV'] || 'development'
```

to

```
RAILS_ENV    = Rails.env
```

That document is 2 years old, bound to have gotchas :)

Comment: now getting: `NameError: uninitialized constant Backup::Config::Rails`

Comment: You might make sure you can run the backup command with no errors, before you start paring down the configuration (since they are old instructions).  First run `backup check` on the command line and see if it tells you your config is good.  It sounds like it might be the rake task that's failing to find correctly.

Comment: All seems to be working. I am successfully able to make backups as well but the issue is with the DB that I need to backup. I will have to hard code if I can not get the rails environment set.

Comment: Gotcha.  In that case - Change the line back to `RAILS_ENV    = ENV['RAILS_ENV'] || 'development'` -- Then set your environment when you run the command if you want it to be something other than development like like :`RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake db:backup`

Comment: This is the command that I use. `RAILS_ENV=development bundle exec rake db:backup --silent >> /var/www/apps/current/log/cron-success.log 2>> /var/www/apps/current/log/cron-error.log`. Now for some reason it does not matter that I am send production as the `RAILS_ENV` value. It always picks the one that is being set in the code.

Comment: If you're setting production on the command line and you're telling it to read the command line settings then if it's pulling a different environment then it's being set somewhere else.  You might update  your question with more information, like what version of ruby and version of rails and what the errors are that you're getting

Comment: `Rails 3.2.11` 
`ruby 1.9.3p0 (2011-10-30 revision 33570)`

I do not get any error. Just the rails env variable does not get passed properly. It is always being set

`ENV['RAILS_ENV'] || 'development'`

as development.